# Force MemoryMappedFile or MemoryMappedViewAccessor to throw on creator disposing the file

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, memory-mapped-files

In my code a producer opens the MMF shared memory by calling

```
_mmfSender = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("SharedMemoryName", size);
```

consumer reads the values via accessor:

```
_mmfReceiver = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("SharedMemoryName");
_memoryAccessor = _mmfReceiver.CreateViewAccessor(0, size)
```

Once the consumer opens the viewAccessor it can read from it even after the publisher disposes the MMF and exits (the values are obviously stale). It can even still read stale values even after I forcefully close its handle to the MMF (e.g. via process explorer).

Is there a way how to make MemoryMappedViewAccessor to throw once the underlying memory is being abandoned by the publisher?
I'm using some extra side synchronization logic to solve this - but having this in the box would be much easier.

Comment: There is no such box.  Adding one would defeat the point of exposing MMFs in .NET since that would just re-invent the abstractions that the operating system already puts on top of shared memory.  Which are readily available in .NET as well, FileStream, PipeStream, Socket and WCF.  CreateViewAccessor() is a kludge, a necessary evil in .NET, MMFs are only fast when you use pointers.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment! Can you share some source of information why and how much is the ViewAccessor slower?
By looking into IL it adds some extra code (probing for stack space, getting the pointer) - but those seem to be just marginal differences.
I wanted to know if there is any existing measurement before jumping into writing my own benchmark.
Thanks!